useLoaderdata gives error 'useLoaderData must be used within a data router' in react
I am trying to load API from the routes using loader, params, and useLoaderData hook.
I used loader params in my existing routing structure and useLoaderData hook in my component but it didn't work.
I checked other questions, but they primarily work on single component routing structure, but for me routing for all components are already done. How can I modify my router accordingly?
<BrowserRouter>
  <Header />
  <Routes>
    <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
    <Route path='/about' element={<About />} />
    <Route path='/services' element={<Services />} >
      <Route element={<WebServices />} index />
      <Route path='web' element={<WebServices />} />
      <Route path='app' element={<AppServices />} />
      <Route path='cloud' element={<CloudServices />} />
    </Route>
    <Route path='/blog' element={<Blog />} loader={fetchPosts} />
    <Route path='*' element={<Page404 />} />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>

function Blog(props) {
  const list = useLoaderData();

  return (
    <div className='blog-container'>
      <div className='container'>
        <h1>Your Blog comes here</h1>
      </div>
      <div className='blog-post-container'>
        {list && list.length > 0
          ? list.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <div className='blog-card'></div>
            )
          }) : <p>No post found</p>
        }
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}


The data loaders can only be used in data routers. Convert your code from using the BrowserRouter to using createBrowserRouter.
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  createRoutesFromElements
  Route,
  Outlet,
} from "react-router-dom";

// Create a layout route component so the header is usable 
// and can access the routing context for links, etc.
const AppLayout = () => (
  <>
    <Header />
    <Outlet />
  </>
);

export const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route element={<AppLayout />}>
      <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
      <Route path='about' element={<About />} />
      <Route path='services' element={<Services />} >
        <Route element={<WebServices />} index />
        <Route path='web' element={<WebServices />} />
        <Route path='app' element={<AppServices />} />
        <Route path='cloud' element={<CloudServices />} />
      </Route>
      <Route path='blog' element={<Blog />} loader={fetchPosts} />
      <Route path='*' element={<Page404 />} />
    </Route>
  )
);

Render the router into the RouterProvider component
import { RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";

...

<RouterProvider router={router} />

Just FYI a route configuration approach may look like the following:
export const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    element: <AppLayout />,
    children: [
      { path: "about", element: <About /> },
      {
        path: "services",
        element: <Services />,
        children: [
          { index: true, element: <WebServices /> },
          { path: "web", element: <WebServices /> },
          { path: "app", element: <AppServices /> },
          { path: "cloud", element: <CloudServices /> },
        ],
      },
      {
        path: "blog",
        loader: fetchPosts,
        element: <Blog />,
      },
      { path: "*", element: <Page404 /> },
    ],
  },
]);

createRoutesFromElements is a convenience utility function.
